# Hibernate for getting a list of primitive integers for subselect

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery

Isn't there a way with Hibernate to return a list of (primitive) values from one column in a table?  I need this for a subselect where I only want rows where a particular field is not in a list of ids from another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it turned to be as simple as something such as the following, from the URL https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html which was actually one of the first results I found when googling but I was concerned it might be NHibernate specific

```
from Eg.DomesticCat as cat where cat.Name not in ( 
select name.NickName from Eg.Name as name )
```

Comment: FYI, the link you posted is to the NHibernate documentation.  The equivalent documentation for the Java version of Hibernate is here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a Hibernate raw SQLQuery?

```
SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery("select int_column from table");
List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) q.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about using the hibernate engine itself, I think this will depend on how youve mapped your model objects, short of seeing the mappings, you can go via the hibernate  session object and use standard SQL;

```
session.createSQLQuery("select idCol from someTable where someId not in (
select someId from anotherTable)");
```

Then use the list() method on the query, and use autoboxing for the primtive int array.